# Chrome can't load HTTPS IP

Tags: google-chrome, ssl, certificate, https, ssl-certificate

I have so many applications that need to load in Chrome via IP but in **https**

1. OpenVas
2. Nessus
3. Kibana and more ..

I kept getting this on each one of them, there is no option for me to click `"Visit Site"` at my owned risk.

[image]

<sup>Click for full size</sup>

I can only see that option on **Safari**.

Why ? Is there a feature in Chrome that I need to enable ?

Comment: Rather than enable you probably need to disable something. Those sites might be using HSTS and something might be tempering with your certs. Examples include corporate proxies or security applications that inspect HTTPS traffic. Did you check the certificate?

Comment: You _really_ should add the certificates or the CA to the list of trusted certificates/CAs. The error will then go away.

Comment: @DanielB I don't know how to do what you propose.